# Facebook iOS SDK - Simple status update with Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to post a simple status update on the Facebook iOS SDK. At the moment, if I include the `link` parameter, everything will work:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = 
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @"Name here", @"name",
                         @"Caption here", @"caption",
                         @"Status update", @"description",
                         @"http://www.apple.com.",@"link",
                         nil];  

[facebook dialog:@"feed"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

But once I remove `link` none of the remaining parameters are acknowledged and I'm left with a blank message. I simply want to perform the same sort of post you can achieve with Facebook request whereby providing a string for the `message` parameter is enough for the status update.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually posing of status messages with feed dialog isn't an option and it's actually not intended to be user like this.

You can consider one of the options:

- Requesting `publish_stream` permission and than issue `POST` request to Graph API with `message` parameter (`feed` connection of `user` object), see [`statuses` connection documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#statuses) (IMO it seems as an good way to go, if you don't afraid to ask `publish_stream` permission).
- Open Facebook App with publishing view (and text pre-filled?), this is described in [answer to "How to programmatically open iOS Facebook app with pre-populated status?"](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7733398/155033)

---

<sub>Note: I'm not completely sure about inability to achieve this with `feed` dialog, so I may be wrong, anyone who know this isn't the case please correct me.</sub>

Comment: There is an [answer to other question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9332820/155033) that have some code sample that partially may fit first option.

Comment: I think I'll just create a custom modal view controller for posting the status, much less fuss! Thanks