# Check success of facebook dialog post in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there a way to check if a post sent via dialog:

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

was sent successfully or not? I've looked through the Facebook iOS SDK and cannot find a delegate method for it. There is `dialogDidComplete` but this doesn't give me information on the success of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `dialogCompleteWithUrl` to ensure that content was posted, as `dialogDidComplete` will not provide those details.

This is outlined in [Sample Application (Hackbook)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook) [dialogCompleteWithUrl](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/4e3567c40e3b7f8156a82f18e5a2f5cd18e077eb/sample/Hackbook/Hackbook/APICallsViewController.m#L1163) (see Line 1182 for exact usage of `post_id` field).

Comment: could you possibly take a quick look at my [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772206/facebook-ios-sdk-simple-status-update-with-dialog), appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the source code of the Facebook finish and you will also see this:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationNamed:@"facebookWallPosted"...

Or similar. Just intercept that notification and do what you need to. Even the failures post the same notification name